# Добавление ActionListener

Tags: java, swing

Цикл перебирает компоненты JPanel, которые являются кнопками, но при этом нет возможности добавить к ним ActionListener, только ComponentListener и FocusListener

```
private void buttonListeners(){
    for(int i = 0; i < jPanel.getComponentCount()-4; i++){
        jPanel.getComponent(i).addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getComponent()` возвращает объект типа `Component`. Чтобы добавить к этому компоненту `ActionListener`, нужно приравнять его к `JButton`.

```java
private void buttonListeners() {
    for(int i = 0; i < jPanel.getComponentCount() - 4; i++) {
        ((JButton)jPanel.getComponent(i)).addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```